# Validation status is return false in JQuery Validation Engine plugin

Tags: jquery, html, validation

I am using the jQuery validation plugin(jQuery-Validation-Engine) for to check email is already taken or not?
It's successfully validating but i am getting validation status is "false" When the email field is show the message "This username is available". Is it error message?
Below is my sample code :
HTML Code:

```
<form method="POST" name="register_form" id="registerForm" >                
    <div class="register">
        <div class="block3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="username1 validate[required]" name="reg_name" id="name" >

            <input type="text" placeholder="Email ID" class="username1 validate[required,custom[email],ajax[ajaxUserCallUserEmail]]" name="emailr" id="emailr" >
        </div>

        <div class="block4">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" class="username2 validate[required]" name="lastname" id="lastname" >

            <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" class="username2 validate[required,minSize[10],maxSize[10],custom[phone]]" id="phonenumberr" name="phonenumberr" />
        </div>

        <div class="register_button">
            <div class="regi_button"><input type="button" id="register" name="register" value="" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript Code:

```
$("#register").click(function(){
    var status = $("#registerForm").validationEngine('validate');
    alert("status== "+status); //Return false

    if($("#registerForm").validationEngine('validate')) 
    {
        alert("hello");

        var fname = $("#name").val();
        var lname = $("#lastname").val();
        var email = $("#emailr").val();
        var phone = $("#phonenumberr").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajaxCheckUser.php",
            data: {"fname":fname, "lname":lname, "email":email, "phone":phone},
            success: function(data){
                alert("data== "+data);

                if(data!=0)
                {
                    //window.location.href=data;
                }
                else
                {
                    //$("#errorMessage").removeClass("hide");
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share your form code?

Comment: Now i am edit my Question.

Comment: So you're saying that it validates correctly, but, the ajax return is wrong? Can you try and explain some more

Comment: Response : "This username is available" message in green color. But consider this message also error. That's problem

Comment: which plugin you are using?

Comment: Plug-in : jQuery-Validation-Engine